# How to resolve the error "Error: Outer container 'null' not found." coming from Jssor Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I've integrated Jssor Slider into my website's homepage. It's working fine on that page, but on other pages I'm getting this error checking Firebug's console:

> Error: Outer container 'null' not found. jssor.js (line 66, col 14)

Line no. 66 in jssor.js is

```
throw new Error(msg);
```

I've included all the necessary files like JavaScript and CSS. Due to this error other jQuery code is also not working. 
I researched about the solution for it, but wasn't able to solve this problem. I have not made any change to the Jssor Slider library at all.

Following is the jQuery code I used to implement Jssor Slider:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  var _SlideshowTransitions = [{ $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }];

  var options = {
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    
    $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  
    $AutoPlayInterval: $('#brand_slider_time').val() * 1000,                            
    $PauseOnHover: 1,                               
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          
    $SlideDuration: 500,                                
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          
    $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   
    $Cols: 1,                                  
    $Align: 0,                                
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                
    $DragOrientation: 3,                                
    $SlideshowOptions: {                                
      $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 
      $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            
      $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           
      $ShowLink: true                                    
    },

    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                
      $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       
      $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
      $Steps: 1,                                      
      $Rows: 1,                                      
      $SpacingX: 10,                                   
      $SpacingY: 10,                                   
      $Orientation: 1                                 
    },

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
      $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              
      $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
      $Steps: 1                                       
    }
  };

  var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);


  function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth)
      jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 940));
    else
      window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
  }

  ScaleSlider();

  if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
    $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
  }

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
  }        
});
```

Comment: It's better to do any call of  functions like [ScaleSlider();] or definition or creation variable like [var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);] just if you had slide to show,  otherwise don't run slider script section and you doesn't have this error.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the code of your page.

The HTML element 'slider1_container' is missing or it has been removed by other scripts.